# Adding loop to ajax parameters

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm looking to dynamically add properties and values to my ajax parameters, does anybody know how to do this? I can't seem to figure out how to accomplish this task. Thanks

doLookup = function($field, url, query, process, filterIdArray) {

```
    $field.addClass("ajax-wait");

    return ajax(url, {
        parameters: {
            "t:input": query,
            "t:inputFilter": $filterField.val(),
            for (var i = 0; i < filterIdArray.length; i++) {
                "t:inputFilter_" + i : $("#" + myStringArray[i]);
            },
        },
        success: function(response) {
            $field.removeClass("ajax-wait");
            return process(response.json.matches);
        }
    });
};
```

Comment: @Arvind Bhardwaj I did last night, thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create parameters outside the ajax function like:

```
params = {};
params["t:input"] = query;
params["t:inputFilter"] = $filterField.val();
for (var i = 0; i < filterIdArray.length; i++) {
    params["t:inputFilter_" + i] = $("#" + myStringArray[i]);
}
return ajax(url, {
        parameters: params,
        success: function(response) {
            $field.removeClass("ajax-wait");
            return process(response.json.matches);
        }
    });
};
```